# Deserialising JSON using JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync is not using my JsonConverter

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, system.text.json

A server is returning a JSON string value which is a URL query string:

```
{
    "parameters": "key1=value1&key2=value2"
}
```

I have a property set up to receive this, and convert it into a `Dictionary` as part of the deserialisation process:

Property with `JsonConverter` attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(QueryStringToDictionaryJsonConverter))]
public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
```

Converter:

```
public class QueryStringToDictionaryJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Dictionary<string, string>> {

    public override Dictionary<string, string> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {

        var queryString = reader.GetString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString)) return null;

        return QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(queryString).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => string.Join(",", e.Value.ToArray()));

    }

    ...
}
```

This should work.

But it's not even getting to my converter.

From what I can tell, `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(myJson)` is seeing that the type of property is a `Dictionary`, and so it tries to parse the value as such on its own, and fails (the resulting exception is an 'invalid cast' as it tries to `GetEnumerable()` etc). A breakpoint in my converter never even gets hit.

I can get it to work by making the property an `object` and then casting to a `Dictionary` later where it's used, but that's an ugly solution.

Is there a way to force `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(myJson)` to just use my converter, without it trying to be smart on its own?

(I'm using Microsoft's System.Text.Json in .NET Core 3)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40405 - does this sound like the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @theduck Yeah thanks that sure sounds like the issue, although it says it was fixed for 3.0, which obviously I am not finding to be the case :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so this could be a bug in `System.Text.Json`.

Here's the workaround I'm currently using for anyone else needing a solution.

First, I set up two properties for deserialisation, using `[JsonPropertyName]` and `[JsonIgnore]`:

```
[JsonPropertyName("parameters"), JsonConverter(typeof(QueryStringToDictionaryJsonConverter))]
public object ParametersObject { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters => ParametersObject as Dictionary<string, string>;
```

And then in the `JsonConverter`, I allow `object` as the type:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) {
    if (typeToConvert == typeof(object)) return true;
    return base.CanConvert(typeToConvert);
}
```

Consumers of my deserialised class just use the `Parameters` property, which will continue to work just fine if and when this bug is fixed and I change the class back to how I'd like it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a wrapper and create a converter for the wrapper.

```
[JsonConverter( typeof( QueryStringDictionaryConverter ) )]
class QueryStringDictionary : Dictionary<string,string> { }

class QueryStringDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter<QueryStringDictionary>
{
    ... 
}

class MyClass
{
    public QueryStringDictionary Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you could use `JsonSerializerOptions`

```
class MyOtherClass
{
   public Dictionary<string,string> Parameters { get; set; }
}
MyOtherClass Deserialize( string json )
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters = { new QueryStringToDictionaryJsonConverter() }
    };
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyOtherClass>( json, options );  
}
```

A potential problem with this approach is that the converter would be used on all `Dictionary<string,string>` properties, which may not be intended. It would work fine for the simple example in the original question.